# Focus out on enter press not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have some input fields and a HTML table on my UI to input some data, my HTML table have some input field inside my HTML table and doing some calculations also all that are working fine

What I am doing is:

- I have some input fields inside my table so when I press on tab I am focusing one next input field
- now there is last input field which is `Disc%` here after pressing `tab` I am creating new row (on focus out) , but that's not a good user interface because whenever I am clicking outside the `Disc%` field it is crating new row which is not correct

What I am trying to do is:

- After `disc%` when I press enter I want to create a new row so that it will be good for user
- I have tried doing this but it is not working correctly as when I reach `Disc%` and press enter it does nothing and when I focus out and again come back to `Disc%` and press enter then it creates new row but on one press it shows three times, I don't know what's wrong

Please [check my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a3hxgf2L/1/), as I have so many calculation that's why code is bit lengthier but I have commented the line where the issue is

- when target matches disc% I am doing like below

  ```
  if (e.target.matches('[name=discPercentagetd]')) {
    $(document).keypress(function(event) {  // here I am trying to create new row when enter is clicked
    var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if (keycode == '13') {
      alert("presed")
      calcDiscount(e.target.parentElement.parentElement)
      if ($(row).parent().find('tr').length - $(row).index() === 1) {
        rowappend(e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement)

      }
    }

   });
  }
  ```

I am doing it like `$(document).on('focusout', (e) => {` because `ItemName` field in my table is `autoComplete` and when creating new row I want it to behave like the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is move the keypress function out of the focusout function that you have. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2gmhxt4b/3/)

Because you are checking to see if they have pressed enter inside the focus out function, it is not behaving as you would expect.

After moving it outside of that function it behaves as expected, the alert is only triggered once, and the row is created even when focus is still inside the input element.

```js
$(document).on('focusout', (e) => {
  const row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement
  if (e.target.matches("[name=itemNametd]")) {  // whene focus is out from itemNametd
    getValues(e.target.parentElement.parentElement)

  }

  if (e.target.matches('[name=unitQtytd]')) { //when focus is out from unitQty
    calc(e.target.parentElement.parentElement)

  }

});

// Move this outside of the above focusout function, 
// you will also need to rename all of the e elements to event, 
// or the other way around. Also include line where you declare the row variable
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
 const row = event.target.parentElement.parentElement
      var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which;
      if (keycode == '13') {
        alert("presed")
        calcDiscount(event.target.parentElement.parentElement)
        if ($(row).parent().find('tr').length - $(row).index() === 1) {
          rowappend(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement)

        }
      }

    });
```

Not question related (since you were talking about user experience):

One thing to keep in mind is "How will the user know to press enter to create a new row". It may be good to also include a button to add a row, and maybe a little element that reveals more information on hover that explains they can use enter to make a new row.

Also, consider styling the total row to look like it is apart of the table, that way the user would know what the numbers match up to.

Comment: Hey there is a reason why I have that code Inside that function because when I focus out from `Disc%`  I am creating a new row,here in your answer when press enter after `Disc%` the new row is not appending

Comment: I have styled that Total row in my original code, and for that enter press, I have also thought of adding a plus button

Comment: Sorry @manishthakur I must hadn't saved the jsfiddle before pasting the link in. Try it now.

Comment: Yup now it worked fine, as you know what I am doing, I just want to have some guidance  am I doing it right way? I will create a plus button to create new row or can have a small info up at my page `to create new row press enter` I just wnat to know am I going the right way?

Comment: Yeah adding a plus button would be fine, maybe add it next to the last row of the table as if I am adding lots of rows then I don't want to scroll back up to the top to add a row you know? Otherwise maybe some text below the table that says `press enter to create a new row` as you said.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is:

```js
const ctrl = document.getElementById("my-ctrl");
ctrl.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        ctrl.blur();
     }
});
```

... which will trigger the `focusout` event of `ctrl` before submitting the form.